# Closure table with heterogeneous types of nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, closures, hierarchical-data, heterogeneous

I'm working with a closure table that manipulate different types of nodes:"program", "project", "region", ....

In fact I have a location table that has the Ids of all my nodes let call this table "StructureElement" . From this table inherit our nodes : "program", "project", "region", ....
Then I have the closure table that links those elements together.

The problem is that I can delete a program from the table "program" and it would still exist in the closure table.

How can I remedy to this without using triggers?

Comment: It might help if you indicated what software or system your question related to.

Comment: @Brian i'm working with asp.net MVC5 and c#